# Firebase returns fields as undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I encounter a problem when I try to retrieve the information I set into Firebase. When I did a console.log I got age undefined and gender undefined.

Below is the code I wrote to set some user information into Firebase. I used the set method because the user will only have one user profile. I do not want the user to add an additional profile which will be the case if I use the push method.

```
onTestSubmit(){
  const { currentUser } = firebaseApp.auth();

  let { gender, age } = this.state;

  firebaseApp.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`).set({
    gender: this.state.gender,
    age: this.state.age
  })
}
```

This is the code for retrieving the information from Firebase.

```
fetchUserProfile(){
const { currentUser } = firebaseApp.auth();
firebaseApp.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`).orderByValue()
.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.value);
})
}
```

The Chrome debugger returns age undefined and gender undefined. My Firebase database is structured as follows:

```
users

  3cUWAm052…
      profile
          age: “32”
          gender: “Male”

  JYPknwOipdS…
      profile
          age: “22”
          gender: “Female”
```

Comment: did you try `snapshot.val()` ?

Comment: Thanks Cherniv! It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To grab the value from firebase you must use `snapshot.val()` not `snapshot.value`

Comment: Thanks wvicioso for ya sharing! :)